# iOS 8.3 Keyboard notification not working

Tags: ios, ios8.3

This is the code for keyboard notification i have written.The following code works fine with iOS 8.1 SDK.But the notification for keyboardWasShown: and keyboardWillBeHidden: is not received in iOS 8.3 device.Is there some issue with iOS 8.3 sdk?

```
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}

- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
}


- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification{
}
```

Comment: From where you are calling the method registerForKeyboardNotifications?

Comment: from the base class written for a view controller.The registerForKeyboardNotifications function is being called correctly,issue only with iOS 8.3

Comment: try to add it in viewDidLoad

Comment: yes the function is called in the viewdidload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the keyboard in iOS 8.3. Uncheck the Predictive and Split keyboard from the Keyboard settings and the notifications works fine.

Answer (score 0):

checked it in 8.4 and it is working fine just check if registerForKeyboardNotifications method is getting called or not

Comment: yes the function registerForKeyboardNotifications is been called, probably  it will be a problem specific to iOS 8.3

Comment: I have build for my app workimg fine on 8.3 using the same function

Comment: that is surprising, but the notification was  triggered correctly in the  iPad with iOS 8.1 but not in iPad with iOS 8.3 for me. Its not working in device, in simulator 8.3,it works fine